Visual analogue scale
I am trying to create a visual analogue scale for my survey. I tried to implement it using the accepted answer for this earlier question:
Typesetting Visual Analogue Scales for questionnaire (within enumerated list)
I tried the following from the answer to the above question:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommand\ScaleLine[2]{%
   \strut\newline (please put a cross on the line below)\vspace* 
   {1em}\newline
   \begin{tabular} 
        {@{}L{0.2\linewidth}p{0.6\linewidth}L{0.2\linewidth}@{}}
        #1 & \rule[-5pt]{0.4pt}{10pt}\hrulefill\rule[-5pt]{0.4pt}{10pt} & #2
   \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item How do you feel today?
    \ScaleLine{Utterly Miserable}{Ecstatically Happy}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\item How was the service today?
    \ScaleLine{The worst I've ever experienced}{Absolutely Brilliant}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\item{etc. \ldots}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

I also want numbers from 1 to 10 on the scale (equidistant). How can I add the numbers?
Thanks

Welcome to TeX SE. What have you tried? Could you edit your post to include the code you tried?

There are a lot of ways to solve this. There should be some TikZ-based solutions on this site already.

There are probably some TikZ-based solutions on this site already. You could also make use of the l3draw package:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ScaleLineRule}{ m }{
    \draw_begin:
        \draw_baseline:n { -2.5pt }
        \draw_path_moveto:n { 0pt , 0pt }
        \draw_path_lineto:n { #1 , 0pt }
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
        \int_step_inline:nn { 10 } {
            \draw_path_moveto:n { #1 * ( ##1 - 1 ) / 9 , 5pt }
            \draw_path_lineto:n { #1 * ( ##1 - 1 ) / 9 , -5pt }
            \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
            \draw_scope_begin:
                \draw_transform_shift:n { #1 * ( ##1 - 1 ) / 9 , -7pt }
                \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin { ##1 }
                \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { hc } { t }
            \draw_scope_end:
        }
    \draw_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommand\ScaleLine[2]{%
  \strut\newline (please put a cross on the line below)\vspace*{1em}\newline
  \begin{tabular}{@{}L{0.2\linewidth}p{0.6\linewidth}L{0.2\linewidth}@{}}
    #1 & \ScaleLineRule{\linewidth} & #2
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item How do you feel today?
    \ScaleLine{Utterly Miserable}{Ecstatically Happy}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\item How was the service today?
    \ScaleLine{The worst I've ever experienced}{Absolutely Brilliant}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\item{etc. \ldots}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


